# check if only one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seven checkboxes, like this:

```
<div class="contact-label span11 rights">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canorder_0" id="contactpersonen_canorder_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canorder_0">Mag border plaatsen</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" id="contactpersonen_canseestock_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">Mag gderen afhalen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0">Mag orders inzien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0" id="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0">Mag bezorgadressen aanpassen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0">Mag netto prijs zien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0" id="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0">Mag facturen en creditfacturen inzien</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0" id="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0">Mag wijzigingen doorgeven</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and I have a javascript function for checking duplicate email, like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }

    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    return ok;
}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

But now if only this checkbox is checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" id="contactpersonen_canseestock_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">Mag gderen afhalen</label>
```

Then is has to skip the email duplicate function

But what is the easiest way to check for that? Or you have to check if every other checkbox is not checked?

Thank you

this is a screenshot for cleareness:

[image]

Oke, but if I do it like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }






 //
$("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").attr('checked', true);
//Alleen een is checked en dat is Mag gderen afhalen
if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
  alert("checked");
} else {
  // any other check box is checked or none
  alert("other combination");
}

//
    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    return ok;
}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

it goes only in:  any other check box is checked or none

see image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr7LQ.png)

If I try it like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    if($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(':checked')) {
    console.log('email is nice');
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }       
        });
    }
    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    return ok;
}else{
console.log('jkshdfkjsdhf');
return;
}}, "email bestaat al" )
```

it doesnt work. see image:

[image]

oke. I have it now like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }

 //


//
    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").attr('checked', true);
//Alleen een is checked en dat is Mag gderen afhalen
if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
  console.log("checked");
    return;
} else {
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    return ok;

  // any other check box is checked or none
  console.log("other combination");
}   



    //if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    //return ok;
}, "Email adres");
```

so I see it comes int:

```
console.log("checked");
```

. But it also comes her in:

```
 }, "Email adres");
```

What ofcourse not has to be.

maybe it is coming because I have above in the file this:

```
contactpersonen_email1:{
                                        required:true,
                                        email:true
                                        },
```

But it is then not required ofcourse if the first checkbox is checked.

Thank you

and if do it like this:

```
if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
  console.log("checked");
    return;
} else {
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    console.log('not checked');
    return ok;

  // any other check box is checked or none
  console.log("other combination");
}   


return;
    //if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    //return ok;
});
```

so this:

```
   });  then I will get this warning:
```

Warning: No message defined for contactpersonen_email

How to combine this method:

```
$('#formid :checkbox').change(function() {
//only one is checked and that is Mag gderen afhalen
if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
  console.log("only Mag gderen afhalen checked");
} else {
  // any other check box is checked or none
  console.log("other combination");
}});
```

with this method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }


    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
    return ok;
}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't you want a radio input?

Comment: thank you. no. not radio. Because you have have checkboxes selected

Comment: UM `$(".checkbox:checked").length`?? Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the specific check by id, and then find out about others by the form id. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57q45k0w/1/) or the attached snippet.

```js
$('#formid :checkbox').change(function() {
//only one is checked and that is Mag gderen afhalen
if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked") && $('#formid :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
  console.log("only Mag gderen afhalen checked");
} else {
  // any other check box is checked or none
  console.log("other combination");
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-label span11 rights" id="formid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canorder_0" id="contactpersonen_canorder_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canorder_0">Mag border plaatsen</label>

      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" id="contactpersonen_canseestock_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">Mag gderen afhalen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0">Mag orders inzien</label>

      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0" id="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0">Mag bezorgadressen aanpassen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0">Mag netto prijs zien</label>

      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0" id="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0">Mag facturen en creditfacturen inzien</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0" id="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0"></input>
      <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0">Mag wijzigingen doorgeven</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will checked it. I will let you know.

Comment: hi. You see the image?

Comment: yes. I saw it just now.  have edited the snippet, run it and check different combinations of the check boxes. The if statement will only be true if ONLY `Mag gderen afhalen` is checked.

Comment: One more thing, I have assigned an id to the root div containing the check boxes. `<div class="contact-label span11 rights" id="formid">`   
This is used in getting all the values of child checkboxes in that div. Add that too in you code when you give this a try.

Comment: Did you see my last update? IT always comes to this line: "Email adres already exist");

Comment: @@ 
Did you see my last update? IT always comes to this line: "Email adres already exist");

Comment: Hi WLatif. How to combine this two methods? Thank you

Comment: Can somebody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Hi WLatif. Ofcourse nice that you helped me. But it is not working in my case. I showed you what my case is. So if you have any more tips. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, I was busy for the last couple of days. I tried to set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nK7Pw/210/) for the defined scenario. Check it out and make some changes according to your need.  
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nK7Pw/210/)

Comment: always a pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

i think your question is about how many are checked, not if a certain one is checked..

`$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length` will give you the number of checked checkboxes..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery for this...

```
//To count how many are checked/ticked
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').‌​length

//To check a specific checkbox...
if(document.getElementById('contactpersonen_canseestock_0').checked) {
    // It is checked, do something
} else {
    // Not checked, do something else
}
```

But if you want jQuery...

```
if($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(':checked')){
    // It is checked, do something
} else {
    // Not checked, do something else
}
```

**Edit:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {

    if($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(':checked')) {
        var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
        var timeRepeated = 0;
        if (value != '') {
            $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === value) {
                    timeRepeated++;
                }
            });
        }

        var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
        if(!ok) alert('Emaild adres bestaat al');
        return ok;
    } else {
        return;
    }

}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

Comment: thank you. But now also other checkboxes can be checked. It has to be that  if only contactpersonen_canseestock_0 is checked than the email validation has to be omttied().

Comment: and that would be a relevant point if he had to include jquery for just this one task..

Comment: The code in my example would only run if that specific checkbox is ticked, for all other checkboxes it would fall into the else { ... } condition. You would need to plumb this into a click event, will update the code..

Comment: @SavantCode I updated my answer with a few different examples as I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Zinc. Yes, oke. But the check email function has to be omitted only and if only if contactpersonen_canseestock_0 is checked. if contactpersonen_canseestock_0 is checked and a other checkbox then the email function has not been omitted

Answer (score 0):

You might simply do like;

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 1
```

In your case more precisely:

```
document.querySelector("div.contact-label.span11.rights")
        .querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 1 ? doThis()
                                                                  : doThat();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want to check if that specific checkbox is checked, With a little bit of jQuery is easy... Use conditionals and :checked, like this:

```
if($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_0").is(":checked")){

     //Skip Function

}
else{
     doThisFunction();
}
```

Hope it helps. Regards :)

Comment: check to see if your answer has already been posted. it's not helpful to have the same exact answer 500 times on a question..

Comment: thank you. But only if that checkbox is checed. So also other checkboxes can then been checked. See my image

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that... while I was writing someone answered the same.

Comment: so that is the point. Ofcourse I can check if all the other checkboxes are not been checked. but that is ofcourse a lot of work. maybe it can the other way. Thank you

Comment: @edd2110. So ofcourse  your suggestion doenst fix the problem.Because what if other checkboxes also are checked.. But thank your for your response anyway