# If checkbox is checked then email field not required

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with some input fields and some checkboxes. Normally a user has to fill in an email address. But if a specific checkbox is checked, then the email address is not required.

This is the HTML for the email:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
  <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
  <div class="contact-input-field">
    <input type="text" class="input-text span2 required contactpersonen-email" id="contactpersonen_email1" name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email",function(value) {
        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_3").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_4").is(':checked')     || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_5").is(':checked')) {
        // && $('#idform :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
                console.log("checkbox true");
                console.log(contactpersonen_email1.val());
                return true;
            }
            else {
                console.log("checkbox not true");
                return false;
            }
        }, "Email adres bestaat al");

        jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };

        $("#idform").validate();
```

So only if:

```
<label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_2">Mag goederen afhalen</label>
```

is `:checked` then an email address is not required.

```
I've made this post earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980216/check-if-only-one-checkbox-is-checked/39980734#39980734

But there was not duplicate email required in that question. 
But now it has, but only if checkbox `contactpersonen_canseestock_2` is checked, then the email adress is not required.
```

if I do it like this:

```
$("#contactpersonen_email1").focusout(function () {
if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").removeClass( "required" );
}
else{
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").addClass( "required" );
}


});


jQuery.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email1",function(value) {




        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_3").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_4").is(':checked')
 || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_5").is(':checked'))    {// && $('#idform :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {



        console.log("checkbox true");
        console.log(contactpersonen_email1.val());
        return true;

        }
        else{
        console.log("checkbox not true");

        return false;

        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };

$("#idform").validate();
```

it doesnt work.

above the document I have this:

```
                                contactpersonen_email:{
                                required:true,
                                email:true
                                },
                                contactpersonen_email1:{
                                required:false,
                                email:true
```

This is the jquery I have now:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email1", function(value) {
        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked')) {
    alert('is checked');
       $("#contactpersonen-email1").removeAttr('required', false);
}
else{
       $("#contactpersonen-email1").Attr('required', true );
}

}, "Please fill in email");




jQuery.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email",function(value) {




        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_3").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_4").is(':checked')
 || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_5").is(':checked'))    {// && $('#idform :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {


        console.log("checkbox true");
        console.log(contactpersonen_email1.val());
        return true;

        }
        else{
        console.log("checkbox not true");

        return false;

        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };

$("#idform").validate();

                        // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
                        $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {

         if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked')) {
    console.log('is checked');
        $("#contactpersonen-email1").prop('required',false);
       //$("#contactpersonen-email1").removeAttr('required', false);
}
else{
  //document.getElementById("#contactpersonen-email1").required = true
       //$("#contactpersonen-email1").attr('required', true );
    $("#contactpersonen-email1").prop('required',true);
console.log('is not checked');
}               


                            html += '<tr>';
                            $(this).find('input').each(function (index, value) {                                



                                // Check if input type is a checkbox
                                if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
                                    var JaNee = 'Nee';
                                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) JaNee = 'Ja';
                                    html = html + '<td>' + JaNee + '</td>';


                                }
                                else {
                                    // Add the value into the html
                                    html = html + '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';

                                }
                            });

                            html += '</tr>';
                        });

                                    // Set the value from the textarea to the generated html
                                    $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').val('<table>'+html+'</table>');
                                });

                            });



              $(function () {
                    $("#accordion").accordion({
                        heightStyle: "content"
                    });
                });
```

And this is my email html:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2" id="contactpersonen_email1" required="" name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is the jquery now:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("CheckTotal",function(value) {
       if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked')){
       $("#contactpersonen-email1").removeAttr('required', false);
    }
    else{
      $("#contactpersonen-email1").attr('required', true );
            }
        }, "Email adres bestaat al");
    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.CheckTotal = { CheckTotal: true };

$("#idform").validate();
```

and this my html:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2 required CheckTotal" id="contactpersonen_email1"  name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

do you want to remove the class 'required' use the below code:

```
if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").removeClass( "required" );
}
else{
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").addClass( "required" );
}
```

do you want to remove attribute 'required' use the below code:

```
if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").removeAttr("required");
}
else{
       $("input#contactpersonen-email").attr( "required" );
}
```

Comment: @
SavantCode What you need exactly?

Comment: Hi I edit the post with your suggestion. But the field is still required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127296/discussion-between-rj7-and-savantcode).

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Yes, but by me thefield is still required. I have added the hole file. It is very big. but ok.

Comment: I think you make this question as a more complex... first edit your question with updated things.. you just added the updates

Comment: Thank you. I changed something. And now it is ok.

Comment: great @SavantCode